# pyspark udf print row being analyzed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, user-defined-functions, static-variables

I have a problem inside a pyspark udf function and I want to print the number of the row generating the problem.

I tried to count the rows using the equivalent of "static variable" in Python so that when the udf is called with a new row, a counter is incremented. However, it is not working:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def myF(input):
    myF.lineNumber += 1
    if (somethingBad):
        print(myF.lineNumber)
    return res

myF.lineNumber = 0

myF_udf =  F.udf(myF, StringType())
```

How can I count the number of times a udf is called in order to find the number of the row generating the problem in pyspark?

Comment: wh the downvote?

Comment: An UDF is applied to each row ... you cannot count the number of line within an UDF because the UDF is duplicated and applied to each rows ...

Comment: If you would have read the question more carefully you would see that I am not trying to count the number of rows directly but trying to have a counter counting how many times the function is called.

Comment: my bad ... but anyway, this is still not possible for the only reason that a dup of the function is executed at a worker level and only the result is brougt back to the driver level. Therefore, you cannot access the final value for `lineNumber`.

Comment: even if I am executing pyspark locally (I mean only on my computer, no distriburion)?

Comment: The solution I can offer you is to output a `struct` with 2 cols : "good result" and "bad result" and then count the bad or good results ...

Answer (score 15):

UDFs are executed at workers, so the print statements inside them won't show up in the output (which is from the driver). The best way to handle issues with UDFs is to change the return type of the UDF to a struct or a list and pass the error information along with the returned output. In the code below I am just adding the error info to the string res that you were returning originally.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def myF(input):
  myF.lineNumber += 1
  if (somethingBad):
    res += 'Error in line {}'.format(myF.lineNumber)
  return res

myF.lineNumber = 0

myF_udf =  F.udf(myF, StringType())
```